# Applying different styles to 2 instances of nivo slider running on one page

Tags: styles, nivo-slider

We have two instances of nivo slider on one page.  One instance displays a different size image than the other.  How can I style these two instances differently?  Specifically, I am experiencing difficulty in positioning the navigation buttons.  I have attempted to create a 'slider2' style, but cannot figure out how to apply this to the theme-default class that controls the navigation buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Houw about giving each nivo slider a diffrent ID ?
and then in the css you can do something like this:

```
#nivo1 .nivo-controlNav { style }
#nivo2 .nivo-controlNav { style }
```

And now you can control each slider buttons/navigation by typing the relevant ID first.